# NSDecimalNumber calculation bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, precision

111...1111 - 111...1110 should equal to 1

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111"] decimalNumberBySubtracting:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1111111111111111111111111111111111111110"]]);
```

I'm using the `decimalNumberBySubtracting:` to calculate it, but I got 0.
I didn't change it to any form of value except stringValue, so I think it shouldn't have any precision loss.

**Result:**

[image]

Is it a bug? I tried it on Google, it answer 0 also.
[image]

Comment: Windows Calculator says 1.

Comment: Show us the code that creates your `NSDecimalNumber` objects, the code that performs the subtraction, and the code that updates the result label text.

Comment: Still no code showing how quotient is created. If someone isn't capable of handling a simple request like "post your code" correctly, I'm not confident that the code would be right.

Comment: One important caveat: The debugger value display is notoriously flaky and may display bad values.  You need to do, eg, `po quotient` in the console to be sure you're getting the true value.

Comment: (Note that you could not have possibly created that value for quotient by multiplying by 10 unless it started out as a decimal fraction with a `.1` at the end.)

Comment: Stupid question: Where are you stopped when you examine these values? If you're not stopped immediately *after* the operations you can end up seeing other values.

Comment: @HotLicks I think it's the true value, because its value also being display on a `UITextField`. For you last question, I stopped right after the line that remainder being calculated. I don't quite understand what you means by the quotient should start out as a decimal fraction with a `.1` at the end ?.? Can you give a example?

Comment: Well, if you would decide what code you're actually executing it would help a lot.  In the first version you posted you were taking 1111...1111 and multiplying by 10.  When you multiply an integer by 10 there will always be a zero on the right end.  But you've changed the code at least twice since then.  (Do you even know what code you're executing?)

Comment: Sorry? I think the problem is in the last line of my posted code. To answer your questions: the first time I post my code, it's about `subtractAmount` = 1111...1111 * 10, second and third time, I add `quotient` to let everyone know where do it comes from, also some comments on it. Is it clear now? Feel free to ask me if you still have any concern of my code ;)

Comment: I tried again with just 16 digits, and works fine. Do you mind giving in a copy-paste-able text the numbers you are using? I dont like counting 1's in an image.

Comment: The number 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 - 1111111111111111111111111111111111111110 = 0

Answer (score 2):

You must have something wrong with your code.

```
NSDecimalNumber *x = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1111111111111111"];
NSDecimalNumber *y = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1111111111111110"];
assert([[x decimalNumberBySubtracting:y] isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"]]);
```

**EDIT**

Your question and original calculator image shows two 16-digit numbers.

However, your debugger output shows that you are actually using numbers that are much larger.  Count the number of significant digits in your numbers, and then read the very first paragraph of the `NSDecimalNumber` documentation, and then answer your own question.  I'll include the summary paragraph from the documentation here for ease of use.

> `NSDecimalNumber`, an immutable subclass of `NSNumber`, provides an
>   object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can
>   represent any number that can be expressed as *mantissa x 10^exponent*
>   where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent
>   is an integer from –128 through 127.

Comment: That's what you say, but I can't see the code creating quotient. I suspect it is the subconscious mind making you avoid posting things that you got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The manageable precision is probably 15 digits, so 1111111111111111 loses the last digit, becoming 1111111111111110 (In the google calculator, not the NSDecimal)

**EDIT:**
I tried this code

```
NSDecimalNumber *x = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1111111111111111"];
NSDecimalNumber *y = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1111111111111110"];
NSLog(@"(%@,%@),%@",x,y,[x decimalNumberBySubtracting:y]);
```

And the log is

```
(1111111111111111,1111111111111110),1
```

Perhaps is something wrong you are doing after?

Comment: NSDecimalNumber has 38 significant decimal digits.

Comment: @MartinR - But the OP hasn't told us how he created his numbers.

Comment: You are right with the digits, I kind of updated, provide some code please